# Adding new data in excel and cannot be sorted or filtered

Tags: excel, sorting, filter

I have a column with 595 rows. Then I proceeded to add 20.

(Note this excel sheet with the 595 entries was already in place before I started working on it. The sort feature was working correctly, as was the filter feature).

So now, I can still USE the sort and filter methods, but it does not take into account these 20 new rows. Any ideas?

Also, I cannot remove the borders on these 20 new rows. They are pretty thick and say I just did 'no borders', it doesn't modify anything.

It seems like there's a 'cutoff' at 595 or something. Very weird.

Comment: how did you add those 20 new rows? screenshot maybe?

Comment: I just started at line 596 and since we are using a 'zebra' type color coding format per row. Ie, row 1 would be light purple, row 2 would be white. So on so on. Since that was the case, I would just copy a row, and paste it at the most bottom point of the sheet (I know I know, not the best way to go about it), delete the current data then add the new data. Screenshot here: http://i.imgur.com/QrPkd.png

Comment: check if there is any active cell-protection, select the whole rows 590-612 and try to reset their borders. clear any filter or sorting and try to reapply them.

Comment: Sorry Jook, how exactly do you reset borders? I removed the filter then reapplied it: didn't do anything. I hit 'clear formats' which removed everything, then doing another sort/filter didn't change the new 20 rows locations (still at bottom of sheet). Under protection in 'format cells', all the cells were 'Locked'. I removed this but also didn't do anything.

Comment: try completely removing the filter and re-adding it after you have pasted the new data in.

Do you have any blank cells in column A? I believe this can cause issues.

Comment: I'm **GUESSING** your original data was formatted as a table and it's not seeing your new data - If that is the case, at the far bottom right in row 595, you should have some kind of a fill handle, drag it down to now include your new rows too, maybe???

Comment: No blank cells in Col A. I removed the 20 rows, removed the filter, added the 20 rows back in, added the filter again. No luck :(

Comment: have you tried to insert a new row INSIDE of your existing 595 rows and then apply any filter? by the way you might have noticed, that we have to guess quite a lot, is it possible for you to provide the actual file?

Comment: Anddddd John Bustos is the man. That's exactly what the issue was. After I did that I was able to change the borders too! Thanks for the all the input :)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution which may not be as obvious is to Un-click the filter button under the data tab and then re-click filter.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After 45 minutes of experimenting and 'googling' for solutions it turned out that the new names I had entered did not have a space in front of them like ALL the other names in that column did. So check to see if the data in the columns are the same distance from the cell wall. If they are different, try adding or removing a space and re-sort. Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using an absence tracker downloaded Excel worksheet from Microsoft, where I added 30 rows. I fixed the problem by clicking/activating the table and viewing the design tab.  Click `Resize Table` and edit the table range.  This color coded the rows and allowed the filter to include the added rows.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, expanding the 'fill handle' as John Bustos (Nov 12 '12 at 17:29) suggested was all that I needed. I didn't have to turn filters off and on afterward either.

Comment: Hi Greg, this is not an answer. Please move to comments.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the Filter, it accounts for the range of data you initially have.  When you add rows, they are outside of that range.  So if you have one additional column that has something in it, like the word "blank" or just "X" or something, and make it go down to row 1000 or 2000 or something, then when you add information in new rows, it should keep the full filtered range, and the sorting would also include the full range, all the way to the row 1000 or 2000 or whatever you make.

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnBustos suggested, the 'zebra' type row color is an outcome of choosing a certain condition in a pivot table.

When you add new rows to a table extracted from Pivot table, in order to include filter conditions/ sort for newly added rows, you need to -

1. Go to far bottom right in row 595,
2. you should have some kind of a fill handle,
3. drag it down to now include your new rows too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there isn't a space before the new data.  That will sort in two batches.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little handle at the bottom right corner of your table (as it exists)...drag this to the bottom of where your new data exists, and it should auto-expand the table to include the table design + filtering. Took me forever to figure out

[image: Handle for expanding table]